# Creating multiple views programmatically

Tags: ios, view

Hello I would like to ask how to create multiple views programmatically and show them on the screen, I have tried this but there is something missing.

```
int x,y;

x= 0;
y=50;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 300, 100)];

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


[self.view addSubview: view];

    y+=40;
}
```

Comment: which method do you have this code in?

Comment: which method do you use this in ? I'm trying to make multiple UIViews in swift but I thought making it like so would override the same and delete the previous one from superview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x,y;
x= 0;
y=50;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 300, 100)];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    [self.view addSubview: view];
    y+=140; //y for next view should be height of previous view and margin between view 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how to make them a rounded rectangle shape ?

Comment: Try to set `view.layer.cornerRadius`

Comment: Hello I would like to ask you how can I update the frame size while dragging it i have tried this code :
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint thisTouch = [touch locationInView:[touch view].superview];
CGPoint prevTouch = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view].superview];
CGFloat dx = thisTouch.x - prevTouch.x;
    if  ([touch view].frame.origin.x + dx < -500)
    {
    [touch view].frame = CGRectMake([touch view].frame.origin.x + dx,
[touch view].frame.origin.y,
[touch view].frame.size.width,
[touch view].frame.size.height);
}

Answer (score 2):

```
int x,y,paddingX,widthOfView,HeightOfView;

x= 0;
y=50;
paddingX = 10;
widthOfView = 100;
HeightOfView = 100;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, widthOfView, HeightOfView)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview: view];

    y+= widthOfView + paddingX;
}
```

Following Code may help to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int x,y;

  x= 0;
  y=50
   for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 30, 30)];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     y+=40;

    [self.view addSubview: view];    
  }
```